# modify data before store with PHP Traits

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits

I try to Encrypt some Keys in Laravel's model with PHP trait

this trait already encrypt value in setAttribute method but data stored without encryption in the database and I don't understand why this happens

also when I use `dump` in setAttribute method everything is ok and values are Encrypted

```
namespace App\EncryptorTraits;


use blackpanda\encryptor\Encryptor;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\EncryptException;
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;

trait Encryptable
{

    public function setAttribute($key,$val)
    {
        if($this->shouldEncrypt($key) && !$this->isEncrypted($val))
        {
            $val = $this->encryptAttribute($val);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key,$val);
    }

    public function getAttributeFromArray($key)
    {
        return $this->doDecryptAttribute($key,parent::getAttributeFromArray($key));
    }

    public function getArrayableAttributes()
    {
        return $this->doDecryptAttributes(parent::getArrayableAttributes());
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->doDecryptAttributes(parent::getAttributes());
    }





    public function doEncryptAttributes($key)
    {
        if($this->shouldEncrypt($key) && !$this->isEncrypted($this->attributes[$key])){
            $this->attributes[$key] = $this->encryptAttribute($this->attributes[$key]);
        }
    }

    public function encryptAttribute($value)
    {

        try {
            $encrypted = $this->getEncrypter()->encrypt($value);
        } catch (EncryptException $e) {
            throw new EncryptException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }

        return $this->getEncryptionPrefix() . $encrypted;
    }


    public function decryptAttribute($value)
    {
        if( !$this->isEncrypted($value) ) return $value;

        try{
            $decrypted = $this->getEncrypter()->decrypt(str_replace($this->getEncryptionPrefix(), '', $value));
        }
        catch (DecryptException $e)
        {
            throw new DecryptException($e->getMessage(),$e->getCode());
        }

        return $decrypted;
    }

    public function doDecryptAttribute($key , $val)
    {
        if($this->shouldEncrypt($key) && $this->isEncrypted($val))
        {
            return $this->decryptAttribute($val);
        }

        return $val;
    }

    public function doDecryptAttributes($attributes)
    {
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $val)
        {
            $attributes[$key] = $this->doDecryptAttribute($key,$val);
        }

        return $attributes;
    }





    protected function getEncryptionPrefix()
    {
        return config('encryptor.db_encryption_prefix');
    }

    protected function getEncryptableList()
    {
        return (isset($this->encryptable)) ? $this->encryptable : [];
    }

    protected function shouldEncrypt($key) : bool
    {
        $encryptableList = $this->getEncryptableList();

        return (in_array($key, $encryptableList));
    }

    protected function isEncrypted($value)
    {
        return strpos((string)$value, $this->getEncryptionPrefix()) === 0;
    }

    protected function getEncrypter()
    {
        return new Encrypter($this->getEncryptionSecret(),'AES-256-CBC');
    }

    protected function getEncryptionSecret()
    {
        $encryptor = new Encryptor();
        return $encryptor->getDatabaseSecret();
    }
}
```

I try to store data Like This

```
$Create = \App\myModel::create([
        'key1' => 'val1',
        'key2' => 'val2',
        ..
        ..
 ]);
```

and also I tried Save method but data still stored unencrypted in the database!

and here is my model

```
<?php


namespace App;


use App\EncryptorTraits\Encryptable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class myModel extends Model
{
    use Encryptable;

    protected $encryptable = ['name'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $table = 'table';

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LeventeOtta data didn't store in encrypted format

Comment: btw, why are you catching the exception to then create a new exception of the same type with the same values and throwing that?

Comment: this is my bad I fixed it now but my problem with storing data didn't solve yet

Comment: Where in this code are you making any attempt to encrypt anything? All you do is create a model.

Answer (score 0):

One of my projects has the same encryptable trait.

```php
<?php


namespace App\Traits\Models;

use Throwable;

trait Encryptable
{
    public function getEncryptable(): array
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'encryptable')) {
            return $this->encryptable;
        }

        return [];
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->getEncryptable(), true)) {
            $value = encrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if ($value !== '' && in_array($key, $this->getEncryptable(), true)) {
            try {
                $value = decrypt($value);
            } catch (Throwable $exception) {
                //
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function attributesToArray(): array
    {
        $attributes = parent::attributesToArray();

        foreach ($this->getEncryptable() as $key) {
            if (isset($attributes[$key])) {
                $attributes[$key] = decrypt($attributes[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $attributes;
    }

    public function decrypt()
    {
        foreach ($this->getEncryptable() as $key) {
            parent::setAttribute($key, $this->{$key});
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```